# subset the data frame based on multiple ranges and save each range as element in the list

Tags: r, list, range

I want to make the data frame as a list based on its values which belong to multiple ranges so that each value belongs to each range to be an element in that list. for example, if I have 10 range and data frame of nrow= n, so I will get a list of 10 data frames.

**The data**

```
df<- data.frame(x=seq(33, 37, 0.12), y=seq(31,35, 0.12))
library(data.table)
range<- data.table(start  =c(36.15,36.08,36.02,35.95,35.89,35.82,35.76,35.69),
                   end = c(36.08,36.02,35.95,35.89,35.82,35.76,35.69,35.63))
```

I tried

```
nlist<-list(
     df[which(df$x>36.15),],
     df[which(df$x<=36.15 & df$x>36.08),],
     df[which(df$x<=36.08 & df$x>36.02),],
     df[which(df$x<=36.02 & df$x>35.95),],
     df[which(df$x<=35.95 & df$x>35.89),],
     df[which(df$x<=35.89 & df$x>35.82),],
     df[which(df$x<=35.82 & df$x>35.76),],
     df[which(df$x<=35.76 & df$x>35.69),],
     df[which(df$x<=35.69 & df$x>35.63),],
     df[which(df$x <= 35.63),])
```

There are two problems. Firstly, I want to make in loop instead of writing the vaules of each range limit. Secondly, this code:

```
Reduce('+', lapply(nlist, nrow))
```

produces the sum of rows = 35 whereas my data frame has nrow = 34. Where does this extra value come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` the data frame according to levels obtained by `cut`ting `df$x` by `range$start`. You don't even need a loop for this:

```
nlist <- split(df, cut(df$x, breaks = c(-Inf, range$start, Inf)))
```

Or if you want it in the same format (an unnamed list in reverse order, you can do:

```
nlist <- setNames(rev(split(df, cut(df$x, breaks=c(-Inf, range$start, Inf)))),NULL)
```

This also gives the correct answer for `Reduce`:

```
Reduce('+', lapply(nlist, nrow))
#> [1] 34
```

Answer (score 2):

you could apply over the rows of your range object

```
apply(range, 1, function(z) df[df$x > z[2] & df$x <= z[1],])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't include the data frames for values below the minimum or above the maximum.

Comment: You're right @AllanCameron, you'd have to include 2 extra rows in `range` that start/end at `Inf`/`-Inf` to capture them all.

Comment: Exactly Daniel. That's why I went with `cut` in the end, because it allows you to pass in a single vector, so you can just stick the `Inf` and `-Inf` on.